# Design: Two Vue Components That Share Similar Sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component, mixins

I am debating about how I should design my Vue components. Here is the problem: I have two Vue components that share the same `sass`.  However, each has a slightly different markup, state, and methods. I was wondering how I can reduce the amount of `sass` code repetition. I don't want to have essentially the same markup and styling twice in two different components. Therefore, I was wondering about what is the best way to go.

---

**Possible Solution 1:**

Make one `base` component that has the necessary sass that is used by both components. Include `slots` to pass the markup from the other two components. In the other two components, add the `base` component and pass markup to the `slots`. This reduces the amount of `sass` repetition by keeping all the common `sass` needed in the `base` component.

**Possible Solution 2:**

Create an extra `sass` file with all the common css and then just import it in the component files that need the styling. I am not sure if this is acceptable in the `Vue` world. I have never seen a project where the author has had a separate file for the `sass`. It's always just included in the single file component. In the `styles` directory, people usually only include the global variables and mixins. They don't include styles that are only used in two components.

**Possible Solution 3:**

Combine the two components into one and use booleans and conditionals to determine what markup and state to use in that one component. I feel like this is bad design because it's essentially like passing a boolean parameter to a function. It violates the Single Responsibility Principle. It diverges the component into two different parts and I feel like it's better to have two components rather than one when this happens in order to prevent the divergence.

---

Those are the only solutions I can think of so far other than repeating the sass in two different files. I am aware of mixins in `sass`, but I am not sure where I should place the mixin. Which directory would this go in and how would I organize it? Additionally, I am also aware of mixins in `Vue`, but I don't think Vue mixins allow `sass` to be placed in them. This is a big dilemma I'm having right now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution 1 is the appropriate approach, though you can use the base component with [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) or [extend](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) rather than slots, depending on what is appropriate.

Comment: @RoyJ can you put css in mixins? also is there any better documentation for extending single file components for vue. the existing docs are really vague and hard to understand

Comment: I do not think you can put CSS in mixins. You would put the CSS in the component that includes the mixin. I keep forgetting that it's [`extends`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) as an option to extend a component. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @RoyJ i tried using `extends` but it's not working. It's not extending the component. Its just creating a new component without extending any of the css or markup. I'm guesing that it only extends the props, data, etc and not the markup. I don't know what to do now. I'm thinking about solution 2 instead now.

Comment: Well, With the possible solution 2, you can import your single SCSS file in the relative component. `<style lang="scss">
@import 'src/assets/css/mycss_lib.css';
</style>`

Comment: Hi @YangK, I'm in a similar situation. How did you end up doing it? I naturally started using option 2, but it felt weird for the same reason you stated-- I haven't seen it being done elsewhere. I thought of extends and I was researching that option when I found your question and saw it didn't work for you. Option 3 is definitely overkill for what I want to do even if I decide to neglect the single responsibility principle. Did you end up going for option 2?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe became useful for you to use a module rule at the webpack.config for sass, where all vue components will share the same archive or variable (you choose!);

### Explaining better

First, you must have the sass-loader in your app.
To know if you already have it at your application, check out your package.json and search for it. If you haven't... run: `npm install -D sass-loader`.

Now that you have it, you can set the following configuration at your *webpack.config.js*:

```
module: {
        rules: [
          // ... other rules omitted
   
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                  additionalData: `@import "resources/css/sass/_variables.scss";`
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
```

Everything that you put in `additionalData` is like if you were adding to all Vue Components. It should work fine.

#### But I don't have a webpack.config.js...

So, if you don't, don't worry. It will be your issue if you started the project using the @vue/cli.

**1.** Create a file at the root of your **vue project** called vue.config.js;
**2.** Paste inside of it the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // pass options to sass-loader
      // @/ is an alias to src/
      // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.sass`
      // Note: this option is named as "prependData" in sass-loader v8
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.sass"`
      },


      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.scss";`
      },


      less:{
        // http://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-strict-units `Global Variables`
        // `primary` is global variables fields name
        globalVars: {
          primary: '#fff'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is 3 different options: **scss**, **sass** and **less**. You choose one more convenient for you and delete the others.

#### I hope to have helped you!